# AJAX response empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've tried this like 8 hours and I don't get it.

With `$.ajax` I get datas from my database via PHP-script. But in this case it doesn't seem to work and I don't no why. The `data2` is empty, no matter what.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://myurl.de/get', 
  data: [{ 'person_id': 2, 'action': 'getLinks' }],
  method: 'POST',
  success: function(data2){
    console.log(data2);
  }
});
```

The PHP-script (important parts) looks like this

```
function getLinks($person_id)
{
    /* sql here */  

    /* format sql-output here */

    return $output;
}

if($_POST['action'] == 'getLinks'){
    echo getLinks($_POST['person_id']);
}
```

The funny thing is, I have the exact AJAX-request in the JavaScript-file some lines above with another action and it works perfectly. When I try to get the data directly in the PHP-file I get the result. The return `$output` is always with the data, but in don't comes to the JavaScript file.

The AJAX always calls the success-function, but with no data2.

Comment: What is value of this `return $output;`?

Comment: Thanks, I got it now, it was because of the array I used instead of only an object in my ajax-request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using only object as `data`, without wrapping it in an array:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://myurl.de/get', 
  data: { 'person_id': 2, 'action': 'getLinks' },
  method: 'POST',
  success: function(data2){
    console.log(data2);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
   $.ajax({ url: 'http://myurl.de/get', 
                data: { 'person_id': 2, 'action': 'getLinks' },
                method: 'POST',
                success: function(data2){
                    console.log(data2);
                }
        });
```

I've updated data line

use this:

```
data: { 'person_id': 2, 'action': 'getLinks' },
```

Instead of

```
data: [{ 'person_id': 2, 'action': 'getLinks' }],
```

Answer (score 1):

data can be an `object` or `string` or an `array`. When you are sending `data` as

```
data: [{ 'person_id': 2, 'action': 'getLinks' }],
```

it will be basically `[>Object]` which is an array of object. You can still send in this way if there is a proper mechanism to retrieve it in the server side.
But sending  `{ 'person_id': 2, 'action': 'getLinks' }` you are sending data as `object` & I presume you server side is configured to accept data in this format